# Lightning Components Basics - Connect to Salesforce with Server-Side Controllers- Queries

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

As part of these module, can you help me understanding the below logic

in order to display the expense from APEX, below is the logic used

```
({
    doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getExpenses");
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS") {
                // var expview = component.get("v.expenses");
                // var parseRes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
                // expview.push(parseRes); // component.set("v.expenses",expview);
                component.set("v.expenses", response.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.log(state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex:code
public class ExpensesController {

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Expense__c> getExpenses(){
    return [Select Id,Amount__c,Client__c,Date__c,Reimbursed__c,Name from Expense__c] ;       
}
```

Aura Attribute **expenses** is getting set with the controller response (**component.set("v.expenses",response.getReturnValue())**;). But If I want to use the commented lines,  by doing a push and then set the component. It didn't work. WHy is that so ? I am doing a component get and then pushing the value which is the way even showed in the later section of this module while saving an expense record.

When to use the PUSH and when i can directly do a component.set?

can anyone help me in clarifying the doubts ??

Comment: Can you try using  var parseRes = [];
 parseRes  = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());

Comment: Why were you trying to parse the result? Isn't it already parsed when you use `getReturnValue`?

Comment: Because I think you are returning list from apex controller which should be stored in array in javascript. And the response is already in stringified format

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria: I tried by making parseRes as empty array and then put the result . but its the same... :(. I even tried by just using json.stringify ; still the same

Comment: @RenatoOliveira: i tried without parsing as well and wihtout stringify as well (all combinations) still it didn't the component attribuute. ..but while i use direct component.set instead of push ...it works...so not sure whats the difference in push

Comment: Can you try using  expview.push.apply(expview, parseRes);
use my above statements in comment(javascript array).

Comment: @AbhikDey - Since you are working with the Attribute `expenses` and it is central to your question, it would be helpful if you also included how you have defined this attribute.

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria: .apply doesn't work in lightning. the code gt failed.

Comment: @Eric:   <aura:attribute name="expenses" type="Expense__c[]" />                             Link to trailhead section: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/lex_dev/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/units/lex_dev_lc_basics_server

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria - Please don't pimp your other questions while one is trying to help you here. If someone wants to answer it they will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you Push you are pushing a single value.

Your `getExpenses` returns a **list** so you would need to **iterate** over the results and push each iteration onto expenses.

In the trailhead module, the push is used as part of `saveExpense` which returns a **single** expense which is why pushing the returnValue works.

So when returning a list simply use `component.set` if you want to replace all values of expenses or if you want to add to iterate over the results pushing each one

<strike>I have not tried it but in principle when returning a list from the controller you should be able to add all values to the attribute using concat as such which would be additive to the existing values.</strike>

```
var expview = component.get("v.expenses");
var parseRes = response.getReturnValue(); //Assuming this is a list
expview.concat(parseRes);
```

Comment: nice explanation and i have verified it :)....i tried pushing one item to it and it worked...expview.push(expviewParse[0]); 'concat' i think nt available in lightnin... anwy thkns again.

Comment: @AbhikDey - did you try concat? Its a standard JS array method so it should be available

Comment: hi.. i tried, it didn work...